# Google Search Console Latest Date

Tags: php, google-search-console

I am using Google Search Console for php to obtain search analytics of my website. I know Google provides data for 90 days, but the end date to that range is not the current date, but usually a couple days prior. Is there a simple way to find the true end date for the data provided? I know I could send requests for recent days and work backwards until a result is returned, but I feel there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

The Search Console provides the Search Data 3 days later. So today (20.06.) you see the data from 17.06. You just have to check at what time the data apears. This is form SC to SC a little bit different.